# php mysql query match for all rows in table when using IN

Tags: php, mysql

I have a trouble when getting all rows while creating filter search in **PHP MYSQL**

For example, my items table contains following data:

*domain:*
**title**

---

Samsung Galaxy

q-mobile S5 series

htc new classic brand

...

*domain* **brand**

---

Samsung

q-mobile

htc

...

How I can get rows when user select to view data for all brand? the query I'm using now is:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FORM table WHERE title  = '$title' AND brand  = '$brand' LIMIT 0,10";
```

Thank you

Comment: Simply don't add `brand` in where clause, that way it will consider all the brands.

Comment: @ShrikantMavlankar thank you. but I have to add it because it's filter search and searching for many columns and don't want to use many if conditions while user selecting data for all types, brands etc. Is there another way possible?

Comment: Just use this : $sql = "SELECT * FORM table";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build a prepared statement with an `IN()` like this:

- build an array with placeholders for each element in the `IN`-clause
- `implode()` the placeholder-array in the query, delimited by a ","
- create an array of the values you want to have in your query (line 3, I don't know in which form you are receiving your values, but this is how you can work with them)
- when executing merge the values of the `IN`-clause with other parameters you might have in your `WHERE`-clause. **Make sure they are in the correct order.**

Code:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=stuff;charset=utf8;', 'root', '');

$brands = array('samsung', 'sony', 'dsf', 'q-mobile');
$title = 'du';

$placeholder = array_fill(0, count($brands), '?');

$placeholderString = implode(',', $placeholder);

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table 
            WHERE title = ? 
            AND brand IN (' . $placeholderString . ')';

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array_merge(array($title), $brands));
```

Add validation of the data you are querying.